# Navigation bar style

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

Hey I'm trying to create an app with a navigation bar that has a title. When iOS 13 rolled around, they seem to have changed some of the properties of the navigation bar so that by default it is invisible. Basically I'm just trying to revert it to its old look. Like this - https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+navigation+bar&safe=strict&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS854US854&sxsrf=ACYBGNQfgNXViu-qZQO1QhlNa1e5MYgBCw:1571459521005&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu3pz0vqflAhUMJt8KHWTFBEUQ_AUIEigB&biw=1326&bih=895#imgrc=CIOME8eGmtDYxM:

[image: My Current Navigation Bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the largeTitle behavior:

```
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

or in storyboard:
[image: IB]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!